# custom widget to retrive price

Tags: magento2, price, custom, widget

I am new to this Magento platform.

I want to create a custom widget to retrieve the price so that I can use it just by calling the widget on the front page.

May anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can create one block file in your custom module like

path app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/Block/PriceWidget.php

```
<?php
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;

class PriceWidget extends Template implements BlockInterface
{
    // Implement logic here to retrieve the product price.
}
```

create widget.xml in the following path

app/code/YourVendor/YourModule/etc/widget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:widget:1.0">
    <widget id="yourmodule_price_widget" class="YourVendor\YourModule\Block\PriceWidget">
        <label translate="true">Price Widget</label>
        <description translate="true">Display product price.</description>
        <parameters>
            <!-- Add widget parameters here if needed -->
        </parameters>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

In the Magento Admin Panel, you can now insert your custom widget into a CMS page or block. Go to the CMS page or block where you want to display the price and use the widget insertion tool to add your custom widget.